# Retrieve the most used 10 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, limit

I want to retrieve the most used 10 records in a field in my database. I used this query but it didn't work !

```
select Top 10 tag from articles order by count(tag) desc ;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Column 'article.tags' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Define *didn't work* - did it give you an error? If so: **WHAT** error? Did it not return the 10 rows you expected? Well, then you must tell us **what rows** you've expected (and why), and what you got instead. Just saying *didn't work* isn't a sufficient description of a problem .....

Comment: well as I said I want to retrieve the most used records .. in my code ( it is the tag field ) ... my code works but it retrieves a different result than what I want

Comment: And as I said : in that case you need to show us what data you have, which rows you **expected** to be selected, and which were returned instead - so that we can see what you **expected** and what was returned in reality....

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 tag, COUNT(tag) tagCount
FROM articles 
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY tagCount DESC
```

Comment: it worked also , why should I use cnt and GROUP BY ??

Comment: @AyaMohammad Because you want most used tags and also you had used aggregate function in your query so you have to use group by

Answer (score 2):

```
Select TOP 10 tag From
(
Select tag,count(*) as total
From articles
Group by tag

) z
order by total Desc
```

Comment: it keeps saying : incorrect syntax near 'order' ,but I don't see any wrong syntax O.o

Comment: have you used `z' ie alias name of inner query , I added it later

Comment: why should I use the z alias ?

Comment: Becuse it is mandatory in SQL server to provide with alias name to a query forming the Derived Table expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can't identify with a simple select top statement. I would suggest you to involve one more table to keep track of id of most selected record  something like this:

```
ArticleId Counter LastUsed
--------------------------
1           5     11/12/2013
3           11    10/12/2013    // and so on
```

Using this table join with your main table and pick the mostly used top 10 ids, based on their counter.

```
Select * From MainTable Where ArticleId in (
    Select Top(10) ArticleId
    From Table
    Order By Counter Desc)
```